# Don't understand cause of this TypeError in subclass definition

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

Described the code and the error below:

Code -

```py
#Inheritance

class Father:
    def __init__(self,home):
        self.home = home

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self,wife,bike):
        super(). __init__(self,home)
        self.wife = wife
        self.bike = bike
        
sonworth = Son("fourbhk","nikita","hayabusa")
print(sonworth.home,sonworth.wife,sonworth.bike)
```

Error -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-b4fa474bd6de> in <module>
     10         self.bike = bike
     11 
---> 12 sonworth = Son("fourbhk","nikita","hayabusa")
     13 print(sonworth.home,sonworth.wife,sonworth.bike)
     14 

TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you missed the `home` parameter from `Son`:

```py
class Father:
    def __init__(self, home):
        self.home = home

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self, home, wife, bike):
        super().__init__(home)
        self.wife = wife
        self.bike = bike
        
sonworth = Son("fourbhk", "nikita", "hayabusa")
print(sonworth.home, sonworth.wife, sonworth.bike)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the `home` parameter from `Son`

You also didn't need to use the `Super()` Function because `Father` doesn't inherit anything

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self,home):
        self.home = home

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self,home,wife,bike):
        Father. __init__(self,home)
        self.wife = wife
        self.bike = bike
        
sonworth = Son("fourbhk","nikita","hayabusa")
print(sonworth.home,sonworth.wife,sonworth.bike)
```

Comment: Thanks , was told by my teacher to use super function actually.

Comment: btw in this circumstance you *should* use `super()` in case this class is changed to inherit from a different super class. Then you don't have to change the code in `__init__()`.